# How to post php files on a webserver in plain text

Tags: php

I want to post all of my source code for a project on my webserver however I have a problem.  All of the source code is in php and when I post it the server tries to execute it.

To try and avoid this I changed the file extension to .html however this did not work.  When I post java files they just show up in plain text is there somehow that I can post php files like this?

Comment: What web server/OS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the extension to .txt?

Answer (score 6):

the `.phps` (php source) extension is supported by some servers and will even do source highlighting for you.

You might have to do a `AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps` in the .htaccess file to get this to work properly though.

Comment: Agreed, out of the box Apache is often configured this way, probably the best choice (out of .txt or some other extension).

Answer (score 3):

If you're using apache, you can add a .htaccess file in your source directory that contains:

`AddType text/plain .php`

Alternatively, you can try using the `.phps` extension if your server is set up for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache and mod_php there should be a line in your httpd.conf file with something like:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php5 .php4 .php
```

Make sure .html isn't in this list.

Comment: A good idea to check since there are a few apps that like to disguise their use of PHP (by using the HTML extension)

Answer (score 1):

use .htaccess directives. unset the php handler and put .htaccess into the directory you want php scripts deny executing

Answer (score 0):

If the `.phps` extension is not supported by your server you can roll your own.

In .htaccess:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine   On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.phps$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)s$ source.php?file=$1
</IfModule>
```

And accompanying `source.php` file:

```
// Basic filename sanitization
$file = './' . preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/\.-_]/", '', $_GET['file']);

if (file_exists($file)) {
    highlight_file($file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run the source code through a code formatter to generate pretty HTML files and publish that as separate HTML documents.